# Supporting LES GetProofs Requests

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients, les

When connecting a LES client to an Ethereum node and sending a GetProofsV2 request, I'm unable to get anything other then an empty (`[]`) response for the set of nodes.  I suspect I've configured my Ethereum node incorrectly.

How can I configure an Ethereum node to respond to GetProofsV2 (or GetProofs) requests?